# Spring MVC moving to next record in list

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to move to the next record in a List that i am returning to a View. Under is an example of what i am trying to achieve i would like to return the second and third record in this list however i would like to return one record at a time from the list:

This returns the last record in the List to the view:

```
 model.addAllAttributes(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
```

Using the under code does not compile:
I get the following message 'The method addAllAttributes(Collection) in the type Model is not applicable for the arguments (Citizens)'

```
model.addAllAttributes(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen).get(2));
```

**Jsp** - just an example of the items on the form

```
<form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" method="POST" commandName="citizens" action="citizen_registration.htm">

<li><form:label for="weight" path="weight">Enter Weight <i>(lbs)</i></form:label>
<form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight"/><form:errors path="weight" class="errors"/>
</li> 
                                                <li><form:label for="height" path="height">Enter Height <i>(feet)</i></form:label>
<form:input path="height" id="height" title="Enter Height"/><form:errors path="height" class="errors"/>
</li> 
                                                <li>
<form:label for="skinColorId" path="skinColorId">Select Skin Color</form:label>     
<form:select path="skinColorId" id="skinColorId" title="Select Skin Color">
<form:options items = "${skinColor.skinColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc"/>
</form:select>          
<form:errors path="skinColorId" class="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="skinColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only assume that `getListOfCitizens(citizen)` returns a`Collection` of `Citizens`. Therefore, `getListOfCitizens(citizen).get(2)` returns just a `Citizens`.

The method [Model#addAllAttributes()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAllAttributes%28java.util.Collection%29) is expecting a `Collection` and you are giving it a `Citizens`.

If you add the whole collection to your model, you can then get whichever part of it you want in your view. You might want to use another method of model, [Model#addAttribute(String, Object)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) as so

```
model.addAttribute("citizens", citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
```

In your view, just use it reference it, depending on your view technology, as `${citizens}`. You can even loop through it or get specific elements at index positions. A quick search of this site or Google will show you how.

```
<form>
    <c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="element">
        The element value is ${element} <br/>
        <!-- put some inputs here with ${element} -->
    </c:forEach>
<form>
```

Comment: yes that is true how can i solve this problem my query returns several records. I need to display all the records and when the user clicks a next record button you change the index and display the next record.

Comment: how can i extract part of the collection in the model?

Comment: I am using Spring form tags so data binding should handle this. The items will not be placed in a list box it will be shown on a registration form.

Comment: @dev_darin See above. Not exactly with Spring tags, since I've never used them.

Comment: I was trying to use `Model#addAllAttributes` like @devdar. What is a code equivalent of this method? I can't find an implementation of Model to learn from. What about `for (Citizen c: dao.selectAllCitizens) model.addAttribute(springGeneratedName, c)` ?